# what is the difference "I am prepared for something" and "I prepared for something"

Tags: word-usage, difference

What is the difference between "I am prepared for something" and "I prepared for something"?

I think both sentences mean I finish preparing for something.

For example in my English conversation class

> Teacher: Hi Koji, how are you? What do you want to discuss today?
>
> I: Hello. I **prepared** my presentation for introducing my company.
>   or
>   I **am prepared** for my presentation for introducing my company.

Is there anything different?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, **"I am prepared for something"** refers to a state of being. You are saying that you are currently ready to do something. However, **"I prepared for something"** refers to a verb in the past tense, **"Prepared"**, and simply means that you helped yourself get ready to do something.

Also, you might want to take note that the sentences in the examples could be rewritten to sound better. Try,

> "Hello. I am prepared for my presentation introducing my company."
>
> Hello. I prepared my presentation introducing my company.

In this case, we probably want to say that we are ready, so we should choose

> "Hello. I am prepared for my presentation introducing my company."

Answer (score 0):

"I **am prepared for** something" means that you are prepared to face its challenges and handle the situation well. For example: "I am prepared for the worst, but hope for the best" (I believe I can cope with the worst situation, should it happen).

"I **prepared for** something" means that you made all the necessary arrangements to be able to cope with something, but now you may or may not be prepared to face it. For example: "I prepared for the the worst, but it never happened" or "I prepared for the worst, but it wasn't enough".

Regarding your specific question:

> I: Hello. I **prepared** my presentation for introducing my company.
>   or
>   **I am prepared** for my presentation for introducing my company.

In the first case, you're saying that you made your presentation ready beforehand for the purpose of introducing your company. So, if you want to present it now, you can, because it's ready.

In the second case, you're saying that you are prepared to make a presentation should you need to, but it does *not* necessarily mean that your presentation is ready already.

Do notice, though, that in the first sentence you did not use "*prepared for*" (as in "I *prepared for* my presentation"), you used only "*prepared*".